# Select all input elements having type text, with matching data attributes value

Tags: jquery, html

I have two html elements with input type text and one with input type button,
And I have clubbed them in one group using data-input-group attribute. Now i want to select all elements having input type text using data-input-group attribute but not button.

Please have a look into code which is not working for me,

```
<input type="text" data-input-group="reg-from">
<br>
<input type="text" data-input-group="reg-from">
<input type="button" data-input-group="reg-from" value="click me" >
<br>
```

and jquery code,

```
var iGroup = $(this).data("input-group");
iGrpElmnts = $('input:not[type=submit], input:not[type=button]').find("[data-input-group='" + iGroup + "']");
/*
* Get all buttons in current form.
*/`enter code here`
iGrpButtons = $("input[type=button]").find("[data-input-group='" + iGroup + "']");
```

Comment: iGrpElmnts = $("input[type!='button']input[type!='submit'][data-input-group='" + iGroup + "']");  worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
iGrpButtons = $('input[type="text"][data-input-group="reg-from"]');
```

Comment: when its `text`, its obvious it cant be `button`

Comment: @Shaddow: Yes, added only text.

Answer (score 2):

Get all the `data-input-group` stuff, then find the `input` with type `text` inside:

```
$('[data-input-group]').find('input[type="text"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("input[type=text]")` to select all elements having input type text

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(":input").each(function(){ 
  a = $(this).attr('data-input-group'); 
  b = $(this).attr("type");  
  if( a !=undefined && b == "text") {
      //here you get the input element with type=text and having data-input-group attribute
  }
  })
```

Please try this